# Regression with coefficients having a multiplicative relationship

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, constrained-regression

Assume I need to calibrate a linear model of the form shown here:

$$Y\sim\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2$$

where the $\beta$ terms are the coefficients and the $X$ terms are the independent variables. The coefficients in this model are constrained like this:

$$\beta_0=\beta_1\beta_2$$

Is it possible to transform the variables in the original model structure to reduce the number of independent variables from 3 to 2 based on this constraint? If so, how?